# Mounting specifics for a ball valve to be manually turned on/off on other side of wall?

Tags: plumbing

I want to mount a 1 inch 3-way ball valve on the inside wall of a pump house but have the valve handle on the outside of the pump house. I also don't want to mount the valve directly on the back side of the sheathing so that I can take advantage of the 4" wall insulation.

(I contacted the manufacturer and they do not have a stem extension kit. I'm not really sure if any other kits are "universal" or only specific to brand/models.)

The valve stem has a 14mm nut. I measured the valve on/off breakaway torque at 10 in-lbs or less. I was thinking to threadlock this nut with Loctite Purple. Then glue a 14mm socket into a custom length pipe and then place the pipe through the wall hole. And then cable tie the homemade extension to the valve body (with socket and nut engaged). Or, leave it off and just hanging near the wall hole. [image: Bench design]

Does anyone have design/installation tips?

Comment: What brand and model of ball valve?

Comment: Nigo Industrial A180SS

Answer (score 1):

Best bet is trying a couple of these and seeing if you can find one that fits the valve :  [www.amazon.com/Midline-Valve-3UVGZ-Extension-Applications/dp/B083B2PG5D](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B083B2PG5D)

You will likely have to extend it to make it long enough to go through a hole in the building. Your biggest issue is going to be length

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot find a manufactured extension that fits/is long enough, consider threading your own piece of metal rod to run through the wall.

I don't know if you'd need a hole & tap on the valve side with a die on the handle side, vice versa, or something totally different, but a bit of brass, copper or even steel rod (steel might rust when exposed to the weather) should do the trick.

You'll probably want to do some extra waterproofing where the handle extension goes through the sheathing, you don't want all that insulation getting wet.